# How to get rid of fine log messages for specific package on Glassfish

Tags: java, logging, glassfish-3

I was playing arround with the log file, somehow I disabled all the log related information but this `javax.enterprise.system.core.security` remains displaying FINE level of log, is there any way to change this one to level WARN and reset rest of the log level to default. I have to scroll too much to find my exceptions.

```
[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.181+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor;MethodName=send_request;|Security context is null (nothing to add to service context)|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.182+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor;MethodName=receive_request;|++++ Entered SecServerRequestInterceptor::receive_request|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.182+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor;MethodName=handle_null_service_context;|No SAS context element found in service context list for operation: _is_a|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.183+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityContextUtil;MethodName=setSecurityContext;|ABOUT TO EVALUATE TRUST|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.183+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor;MethodName=receive_reply;|++++ Entered SecClientRequestInterceptor::receive_reply|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.184+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor;MethodName=handle_null_service_context;|No SAS context element found in service context list|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.184+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor;MethodName=setreplyStatus;|Status to be set : 0|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.185+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityContextUtil;MethodName=receivedReply;|Passed status|#]

[#|2014-07-28T14:02:42.185+0500|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor;MethodName=setreplyStatus;|Invoked receivedReply()|#]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using log4j, you can create log4j categories and subsequent appenders to control logging.

E.g: Category:

```
log4j.category.javax.enterprise.system.core.security=WARN, S
```

Appender:

```
log4j.appender.S=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.S.File=${myWebapp-instance-root}/log/External.log
log4j.appender.S.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.S.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.S.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
```